# Trigger with result of first query use as a variable in second query

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I am trying to make a trigger in MySQL that when I will update the table I will insert old values to history table, but the problem here is that in the moment that I am doing insertion I need to execute a select query that will return me an Id that i need to use in insertion does this is possible.

this is the trigger:

```
SET @bedroomHistoryId = (SELECT id from bedroomhistory ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1);

INSERT INTO objecthistory (
      name,street,poBox,zipcode,city,
    idCountry,idRegion,mapLocation,numberOfRooms,comment,
    wlanCheck,ssid,password,giftBox,parkingIndoor,
    parkingOutdoor,parkingInformations,preparation,intermediateCleaning,finalCleaning,
    finalCleaningUntil,keyHandover,idBedroom,idLandlord,
    idCaretaker,idObject,modifiedByUserID,changed
) VALUES (
    OLD.name,OLD.street,OLD.poBox,OLD.zipCode,OLD.city,
    OLD.idCountry,OLD.idRegion,OLD.mapLocation,OLD.numberOfRooms,OLD.comment,
    OLD.wlanCheck,OLD.ssid,OLD.password,OLD.giftBox,OLD.parkingIndoor,
    OLD.parkingOutdoor,OLD.parkingInformations,OLD.preparation,OLD.intermediateCleaning,OLD.finalCleaning,
    OLD.finalCleaningUntil,OLD.keyHandover,@bedroomHistoryId,OLD.idLandlord,
    OLD.idCaretaker,OLD.id,OLD.modifiedByUserID,NEW.changed
)
```

when I try to save the trigger like this i get this message: **1054 - Unknown column 'OLD.name' in 'field list'**

if I remove

```
SET @bedroomHistoryId = (SELECT id from bedroomhistory ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1);
```

then the trigger it works.

Comment: Please add create statement

Comment: DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `objectTrack`;
delimiter ;;
CREATE TRIGGER `objectTrack` AFTER UPDATE ON `object` FOR EACH ROW SET @bedroomHistoryId = (SELECT id from bedroomhistory ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1);
;;
delimiter ;

but doesn't let me to write INSERT INTO query

Comment: You cannot refer to OLD. Values in an after update trigger see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html